# Access to components (textBox) in pivot Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

is possible to access to components in Pivot ? I have textBox in pivot and I would like change this text in code behind, but I don't see this component in my code. I tryed set `x:FieldModifier="public"` but still I don't have acces to this component.
Thanks

```
     <PivotItem  Header="Termíny" Margin="19,23,19,50">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <ListView SelectionMode="None" x:Name="ListBox1" Margin="0,0,-0.167,0.167"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                        ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True"
   ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                                <Grid>

                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="14.5,0,0,0">
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtTest" Text="test" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding jmeno}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding prijmeni}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
                                    </StackPanel>

                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding termin}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />

                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="{Binding skutecny_termin}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}"  />

                                        </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
<Button Content="nacti" Grid.Row="2" Click="Button_Click" />
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
```

Comment: Can you please share your XAML code?

Comment: Updated xaml code - it is textBox "txtTEst"

Comment: You're asking about a TextBox yet your xaml holds only TextBlocks.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was wrong about textBox. IT is textBlock.

Answer (score 0):

since your textblock is inside the datatemplate the only way to modify it is by using viewmodel and bind the text desired properties, or if it is not necessary to use viewmodel you have to put the textblock outside the datatemplate and you can access it in code behind.